# Ransack advanced search on heroku results in application error due to time out and server crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using ransack for advanced search on heroku. When search results is quite heavy, then it raise application error due to time out.

Is there any way to optimized the search without increasing the server memory?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your search criteria, it can be very slow regardless the memory, you should inspect the SQL created by ransack and create some indexes to speed up your query. Look at you log for the generated SQL and make sure you are using the correctd index